# Building a filtering system using both OR and AND relations

Tags: categories, relations, logic

I'm trying to set up a filtering system similar to the [one found on the product pages on asos.com](http://www.asos.com/men/shoes-boots-trainers/cat/?cid=4209&refine=attribute_1027:7504%7Cbase_colour:11,16,33&currentpricerange=0-290&pgesize=36). That system has different category groups of filters, where selecting multiple filters inside a particular category group widens the results list (OR / conjuction), whereas filters across category groups narrow the results list (AND / disjunction).

I'm trying to replicate this behaviour in Craft, but I'm struggling to combine AND and OR relations. I currently do the following to build up a list of filters across category groups from a comma separated query string in the form `?regions=22,33&teams=65&sectors=42,43,44`:

```
{% set categoryGroups = ['regions', 'teams', 'sectors', 'topics'] %}
{% set relations = ['and'] %}
{% for group in categoryGroups %}
  {% set filterValueString = craft.request.getParam(group) %}
  {% if filterValueString != '' %}
    {% set filterValues = filterValueString|split(',') %}
    {% set relations = relations|merge(filterValues) %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if relations | length > 1 %}
  {% set params = params | merge({ relatedTo: relations }) %}
{% endif %}

{% set results = craft.entries(params) %}
```

This results in a `relations` array which looks like `['and', 22, 33, 42, 43, 44, 65]`, and creates a system where adding a filter to an already filtered category group restricts the result set further, instead of widening it to encompass the new filter. I thought perhaps that I could construct `relations` to look like `['and', [22, 33], [42, 43, 44], 65]`, and the inner arrays (category groups) would default to an OR (as it would when passing a standard array of element IDs into `relatedTo`), with the outer relation providing the AND, but this doesn't appear to work.

Is there anyway to get the behaviour I'm looking for?

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure if twig is suited for that. My hint would be: create a plugin variable and do it with php, you can create a query from your `ElementCriteriaModel` and include your conditions freely like you want

Comment: Agreed, this was probably a little much for twig but I got to a solution!

Answer (score 2):

I've looked at it further and arrived at a solution.

The `relations` array needed to be in the form `['and', {element: [22, 33]}, {element: [42, 43, 44]}, {element: 65}]`.

So that could be done using the following:

```
{% set relations = relations|merge([{element:filterValues}]) %}
```